# Why the browser window closing works only half the time

Tags: php, mysql, browser, tabs, report

I have a big `php/mysql` application with so many `sql` queries that generate `report`, and the report is done it send an email with the report link.

The only thing's that if I left the `windows open`, the report `generate fully` and I receive an email with the link to the report, but when `I close the browser` windows, the tool generate `half of the data` and send an email.

**Mainly why the window closing works only half the time.**

Comment: And that's why we don't execute long processes from the browser. Use a queue.

Comment: can you please tell more about `queue`, a link will be very helpful. thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't link to anything more useful than the results available on Google for [php queue](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&gs_rn=11&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=ZXqb9kVm1zQqlqTmcyiTqw&cp=8&gs_id=w&xhr=t&q=php+queue&es_nrs=true&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=php+queu&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.ZWU&fp=b1925784c73ac81a&biw=1235&bih=683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of ignore_user_abort and set_time_limit:

```
ignore_user_abort(true); // continue to run after client disconnects
set_time_limit(0); // infinite time limit
```

Rather than an infinite time limit, you could estimate the number of seconds the script will need and pad more time on to it. That way the script won't have a chance to hang the process.

Comment: You have to be very careful when you use either of these functions alone, and *especially* so when using them together. If your code mistakenly hangs or gets into an infinite loop it will not stop until someone logs onto the server and kills the process manually.